# Hyperlink in DataGridView - how to have text and links?

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview

Is it possible to have a Windows Forms DataGridView in which one of the columns will display standard text with some words of it as clickable links? Here's what I'd like to do: whenever I get a certain regex pattern in the text, I want to make that match a hyperlink.

Any idea on how to implement this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, to do what you want to do I think you would need a custom control that derives from the IDataGridViewEditingControl interface, which you could then plug into your DataGridView.  [This article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/RtfInDataGridView.aspx) shows how to do this with a RichTextBox.

Unfortunately I don't think a drop-in solution exists, unless you're willing to go commercial.  [Infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/winforms.aspx#Overview) has a [WinGrid](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/winforms/wingrid.aspx#Overview) control with which they claim you can plug in a [WinFormattedTextEditor](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/NET/2008.2/CLR2.0/html/WinFormattedTextEditor_About_WinFormattedTextEditor.html) that supports hyperlinks.